# VBA add image in cell gives different results

Tags: excel, vba, image

I have a question about a problem that I can't seem to solve.
I have some VBA-code that includes a picture in a cell:

```
fNameAndPath = UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value

Set img = Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(fNameAndPath, False, True, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    
    With img

        .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Lastrow).Left
       .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Lastrow).Top
       .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Lastrow).Width
       .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Lastrow).Height
       .Placement = 1
    
       
    End With
```

This code runs perfectly for myself. The pictures are beautifully inserted.
However, 20% of my colleagues who use the macro find their picture in column H instead of column G.

I cannot come up with a reason why this happens.
Someone who encountered a related issue?

Thank you

Comment: Do they have the sheet window zoom set to anything other than 100%?

Comment: I would save the ```ActiveSheet``` into a local variable ```Dim sht As Worksheet: Set sht = ActiveSheet``` and then use that variable instead. It might be possible that the active sheet is changed while the macro runs so it is always best to protect against this type of edge cases. You don't want to read the ```.Left``` property from another sheet's G column

Comment: I can not for the life of me replicate this problem - I have tried all sorts of zooms etc. but they all end up perfectly in position (like it does for you!). Is there any other code, not included in your example, that runs after this that could be inserting / removing columns?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, hereby the whole code that is in this macro.

```
Sub CommandButton3_Click()
‘ check whether conditions are OK
If UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = "" Or UserForm1.TextBox2.Value = "" Or UserForm1.TextBox3.Value = "" Or UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
MsgBox ("")
Exit Sub
End If
‘Check whether a picture was attached
If UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value = "" Then
MsgBox ("")
Exit Sub
End If
Workbooks("").Sheets("").Unprotect ""

‘Find username of the user
Dim username As String
username = Environ("username")

‘define lastrow and write some data in the cells
Lastrow = Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("A650000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("A" & Lastrow).Value = "=Now()"
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("A" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("A" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("B" & Lastrow).Value = ""
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("C" & Lastrow).Value = username
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("C" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("C" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("D" & Lastrow).Value = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("E" & Lastrow).Value = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("F" & Lastrow).Value = UserForm1.TextBox3.Value
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("H" & Lastrow).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("I" & Lastrow).Value = ""
Worksheets("Objets Inutiles").Range("J" & Lastrow).Value = ""

fNameAndPath = UserForm1.ComboBox2.Value

Set img = Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(fNameAndPath, False, True, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    
    With img
       'Resize Picture to fit in the range....
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Lastrow).Left
       .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Lastrow).Top
       .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Lastrow).Width
       .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Lastrow).Height
       .Placement = 1
           
    End With
   ‘send some spam around

Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Source As String
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application
Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
EmailItem.To = ""
EmailItem.CC = ""
EmailItem.BCC = ""
EmailItem.Subject = ""
EmailItem.HTMLBody = ""

EmailItem.Send
Unload UserForm1
Workbooks("").Sheets("").Protect ""
Workbooks("").Save
MsgBox ("")
Exit Sub
Unload Me
Workbooks("").Sheets("").Protect "Sapore"
Workbooks("").Save
MsgBox ("")
End Sub
```